# How to concat to access cell using vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2010, concatenation

I want to concat(add to what already exist) to an access cell using the text from a vb.net textbox. I tried using UPDATE but I'm getting a syntax error. This is what I tried so far

```
Dim ds As New DataSet()
Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\equip_full.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=matt"

Dim db As String = "Update INTO Equipment set TypeItem = ISNULL(TypeItem, '') & @EquipmentItem  WHERE EquipmentCat = @category"

 Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)
     Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(db, cn)
     cn.Open()
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@EquipmentItem", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Form4.TextBox1.Text & ";"
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@category", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Me.item_text.Text
          Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()    
          'some code...
          End Using
      End Using
 End Using
```

Comment: show us the error. in vb or sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for an Update query is

```
UPDATE tablename SET field=value, field1=value1,.... WHERE condition
```

Then you need to remove that INTO that is used in the INSERT queries

```
Dim db As String = "Update Equipment set TypeItem = .... " & 
                   "WHERE EquipmentCat = @category"
```

After fixing this first syntax error, then you have another problem with `ISNull`
ISNull is a boolean expression that return true or false.
If you want to replace the null value with an empty string you need the help of the IIF function that you could use to test the return value of ISNull and prepare the base string to which you concatenate the @Equipment parameter.

Something like this

```
Dim db As String = "Update Equipment " & _ 
"set TypeItem = IIF(ISNULL(TypeItem),'', TypeItem) & @EquipmentItem  " & _
                   "WHERE EquipmentCat = @category"
```